# Alternative to like for Text search

Tags: mysql, wildcard, sql-like, text-mining

I have two tables, one contains application names, acronyms and aliases (TBL_APPLICATIONS) the other contains text in three columns i.e. title, description and resolution (TBL_LOGS). I need to find application parameters in those three text columns in order to search for probable relations. My SQL looks like this:

```
select i.id,ap.ApplicationID 
from TBL_LOGS i 
INNER JOIN 
TBL_APPLICATIONS ap      
ON 
(
i.title LIKE CONCAT('% 'ap.name ,' %') OR 
i.title LIKE  CONCAT('% ', ap.acronym ,' %') OR 
i.title LIKE CONCAT('% ', ap.alias ,' %') OR 
i.description LIKE CONCAT('% ', ap.name ,' %') OR 
i.description LIKE  CONCAT('% ', ap.acronym ,' %') OR 
i.description LIKE CONCAT('% ', ap.alias ,' %') OR 
i.resolution LIKE CONCAT('% ', ap.name ,' %') OR 
i.resolution LIKE  CONCAT('% ', ap.acronym ,' %') OR 
i.resolution LIKE CONCAT('% ', ap.alias ,' %')
);
```

DB is MySQL, The Three columns in the TBL_LOGS are longtext type. This SQL takes 8 minutes to execute, the data in both the tables is about 60K rows. Is there a way to do this without like and wildcard?

Comment: Checkout mysql full text search.

Comment: It takes so long because you need to join the tables and then use WHERE clauses to execute the search. Joining the tables on 9 conditions is doomed to go bad. 
Find another way to join your tables and use a simple and effective WHERE clause.

Comment: @PatrickAleman I agree with you on the join conditions. I tried using where clause but there were no significant improvements. I think the explain plan for both is same.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty isnt that supposed to work on indexed columns?